# Unable to view UITableViewCell when using custom cell's in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a custom UITableViewCell in my application to display a simple label for each row.  However, for some reason I am unable to display the contents of the array that contains the text I want to display in each cell.  I made my custom UITableViewCell in a .xib file using Interface Builder, and my viewController that is using this custom UITableViewCell is inside my storyboard file.

Here is what my screen looks like in IB:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the relevant method inside my custom UITableViewCell class:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Because I've done everything inside IB, I didn't include any code inside the initWithStyle method.

My relevant code inside my ViewController where I am using the custom cell is as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.menuArray = @[@"Apples", @"Pears", @"Bananas", @"Oranges", @"Peaches"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MenuTableCell *cell = (MenuTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = (MenuTableCell *)[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.menuLabel.text = [self.menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.menuArray count];
}
```

Can anyone see what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: why you are cretaing the 3 cell, 1 is enough

Comment: and declare the number of rows in section

Comment: I'm not creating three separate cells, that's the same cell, but different views of the tool bar on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the required methods below in your viewController

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.menuArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

    return [self.menuArray count];
}
```

And I have edited the cellForRowAtIndexPath have a look at it

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MenuTableCell *cell = (MenuTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    //Edited Code for creating the cell*****************************************            
    if (cell == nil) 
    {

          NSArray *objectsArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuTableCell" owner:self options:nil];

          for (id objectCell in objectsArray)
          {
                cell = (MenuTableCell*)objectCell;
          }
    }

    cell.menuLabel.text = [self.menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution, my code is almost working.  For some reason, each table cell is displaying the text "label" instead of the appropriate value from self.menuArray.  Can you see why?

Comment: @syedfa Hey you can write down an `NSLog(@"currentLabel:%@",[self.menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);` and see what it actually returns. If it is returning what you want then might be you havent linked the menuLabel to the label in xib

Answer (score 1):

If you make a cell in a xib file, you should call registerNib:forIdentifier: in viewDidLoad. If you do this, it's unnecessary to check for a nil cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  I'm almost there.  For some reason, my table cell's are displaying "Label" now, instead of the correct value from the array.  Can you see why?

Comment: Also, if I do as you suggest, how would I call registerNib:forIdentifier from viewDidLoad, and what would my code in my cellForRowAtIndexPath look like then?  Would I simply remove the if (cell == nil) block altogether?

Comment: @syedfa, yes, you can delete the cell==nil block. It's called like this -- [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SampleCell1" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SampleCell1"];

Answer (score 1):

I Think This Will Work for You.... And Also Check your Label Outlet Connection For Displaying Proper Answer

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{
      return [menuArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

       CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil)
   {
       NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
       cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }
     cell.menuLabel.text = [self.menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `numberOfRowsInSection` method in `yourViewController` like below

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.menuArray count];
}
```